# Are short squeezes becoming more common, and if so, why?

Tags: stock-market, financial-markets, trading

This year I have read about short squeezes more often than any time in the past.  Are short squeezes becoming more common, and if so, why?

Comment: Not at all sure, but this might be a better fit for [Money.SE] or [Quant.SE]?

Comment: I'm still interested in this question, in case anyone has an answer.